# Download 'El Capitan', 'Mavericks' or 'Yosemite' from external link

Tags: macos, install

The HDD of my MacBook Pro (2012) dies and I bought a new one. The problem is that I don't have another Mac to download the OS from Apple Store...

Someone know from where can I download the OS El Capitan, Mavericks or Yosemite to install it and then download 'El Capitan' and from Apple Store and make a clean installation?

Comment: BTW I have downloaded several torrents but are 'Virtual Machine Disk Format'... Thanks

Comment: Hey @klanomath sorry for my bad English... I'm not native speaker.... ;)

Comment: Please add your Mac model

Comment: I think it's irrelevant but is... 'Macbook pro from 2012' thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you've updated your MacBook Pro with the newest firmware update you may start to Internet Recovery Mode and reinstall the original OS X (probably Lion).

- Install your new HDD
- Detach any external drive (especially any external Time Machine backup drive).
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot to a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an apple/akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.
- In the opening window choose *Disk Utility*.
- Partition your drive: 1 (or more) partition, GUID partition table, Journaled HFS+.
- Quit Disk Utility and open *Restore OS X*
- Choose your new volume to install OS X there.
- After successfully installing and configuring OS X, open App Store and install the latest OS X (El Capitan).